A step into darkness: Historical Judeo-Christian relations in the early church, does it persist in the modern era?
I recently took a "plunge" into the Jewish SE and noticed a very strong anti-christian sentiment from some of the active and "vocal" members. Some of this was my own reaction, but when viewed by others they agreed (in varying amounts) that it was anti-christian. To be fair, they are supposed to not allow the temptation of idolatry even start at all. (To the point of not even enjoying the physical beauty of a church)
They view the New Testament as "sly" and "sneaky" full of references to make the jewish people seem lesser or cursed. As well as many other things. Some of this was likely due to a generalization against Christians, because of bad people who twisted scripture one way or the other. That type of thing does happen and it is invariably a regrettable fruit of having no spiritual guidance. And as much fun as it would be to "rip apart" the protestants or the "crusaders" that is not going to help anyone either. (And yes, nazi's were evil, stalin was also evil and worse, ho hum, off topic)
I can understand the original animosity from Jews towards Christians. After all we are "jewish heretics" from their perspective. And that part is perfectly understandable.
And I can understand the early church being very hostile towards jewish religious leaders, considering they had been hunted by them before that, and they outright rejected the Messiah.
But... I mean... oh just read some of it and maybe it makes a little bit of sense why they feel like they have been "persecuted" for 2000+ years.

St John Chrysostom: Adversus Jedaeos (Against the Jews) Homily 1.


I
(4) And so I wanted again today to engage in that contest. For if the enemies of the truth never have enough of blaspheming our Benefactor, we must be all the more tireless in praising the God of all. But what am I to do? Another very serious illness calls for any cure my words can bring, an illness which has become implanted in the body of the Church. We must first root this ailment out and then take thought for matters outside; we must first cure our own and then be concerned for others who are strangers.
(5) What is this disease? The festivals of the pitiful and miserable Jews are soon to march upon us one after the other and in quick succession: the feast of Trumpets, the feast of Tabernacles, the fasts. There are many in our ranks who say they think as we do. Yet some of these are going to watch the festivals and others will join the Jews in keeping their feasts and observing their fasts. I wish to drive this perverse custom from the Church right now. My homilies against the Anomians can be put off to another time, and the postponement would cause no harm. But now that the Jewish festivals are close by and at the very door, if I should fail to cure those who are sick with the Judaizing disease. I am afraid that, because of their ill-suited association and deep ignorance, some Christians may partake in the Jews' transgressions; once they have done so, I fear my homilies on these transgressions will be in vain. For if they hear no word from me today, they will then join the Jews in their fasts; once they have committed this sin it will be useless for me to apply the remedy.
(6) And so it is that I hasten to anticipate this danger and prevent it. This is what physicians do. They first check the diseases which are most urgent and acute. But the danger from this sickness is very closely related to the danger from the other; since the Anomians impiety is akin to that of the Jews, my present conflict is akin to my former one. And there is a kingship because the Jews and the Anomians make the same accusation. And what charges do the Jews make? That He called God His own Father and so made Himself equal to God. The Anomians also make this charge-I should not say they make this a charge; they even blot out the phrase "equal to God" and what it connotes, by their resolve to reject it even if they do not physically erase it.
II
But do not be surprised that I called the Jews pitiable. They really are pitiable and miserable. When so many blessings from heaven came into their hands, they thrust them aside and were at great pains to reject them. The morning Sun of Justice arose for them, but they thrust aside its rays and still sit in darkness. We, who were nurtured by darkness, drew the light to ourselves and were freed from the gloom of their error. They were the branches of that holy root, but those branches were broken. We had no share in the root, but we did reap the fruit of godliness. From their childhood they read the prophets, but they crucified him whom the prophets had foretold. We did not hear the divine prophecies but we did worship him of whom they prophesied. And so they are pitiful because they rejected the blessings which were sent to them, while others seized hold of these blessing and drew them to themselves. Although those Jews had been called to the adoption of sons, they fell to kinship with dogs; we who were dogs received the strength, through God's grace, to put aside the irrational nature which was ours and to rise to the honor of sons. How do I prove this? Christ said: "It is no fair to take the children's bread and to cast it to the dogs". Christ was speaking to the Canaanite woman when He called the Jews children and the Gentiles dogs.

Note "The Root" referred to above is from the common practice of grafting, branches can be grafted onto different roots and different fruit bearing trees.
Similar to this verse: Romans 11:18 do not be arrogant toward the branches; but if you are arrogant, remember that it is not you who supports the root, but the root supports you.

III
Many, I know, respect the Jews and think that their present way of life is a venerable one. This is why I hasten to uproot and tear out this deadly opinion. I said that the synagogue is no better than a theater and I bring forward a prophet as my witness. Surely the Jews are not more deserving of belief than their prophets. "You had a harlot's brow; you became shameless before all". Where a harlot has set herself up, that place is a brothel. But the synagogue is not only a brothel and a theater; it also is a den of robbers and a lodging for wild beasts. Jeremiah said: "Your house has become for me the den of a hyena". He does not simply say "of wild beast", but "of a filthy wild beast", and again: "I have abandoned my house, I have cast off my inheritance". But when God forsakes a people, what hope of salvation is left? When God forsakes a place, that place becomes the dwelling of demons.
(2) But at any rate the Jews say that they, too, adore God. God forbid that I say that. No Jew adores God! Who say so? The Son of God say so. For he said: "If you were to know my Father, you would also know me. But you neither know me nor do you know my Father". Could I produce a witness more trustworthy than the Son of God?
(3) If, then, the Jews fail to know the Father, if they crucified the Son, if they thrust off the help of the Spirit, who should not make bold to declare plainly that the synagogue is a dwelling of demons? God is not worshipped there. Heaven forbid! From now on it remains a place of idolatry. But still some people pay it honor as a holy place.

Now I get that St. Chrysostom was... upset to put it mildly. And I think I have not done us much favors by quoting it. But to my understanding he is not saying that he "held a nation" or "held a faith" responsible, and that is not how they used the word "jew" and "race" 2000 years ago either...
But given how ... inflammatory this subject can be. It is hard to find any proper information, because if you search for it you overwhelmingly get results based on the modern climate.
Ultimately the question I have are the following:

Is christianity in the modern sense "anti-semitic"? I don't believe so.
Is early christianity "anti-jew"? I feel like it has to be...

A defense for St. John Chrysostom, the most outspoken church father against "jews" would be nice. But that is a historical issue.
Answers should include your personal theological inclination at the start or end, so things are clear and easy to understand. (aka: which church are you from?)
Note: I did not pick a particular denomination, this is because I am out of tags. Answers from the perspective of churches who have apostolic succession are preferred, but if a protestant has an answer I won't refuse.

Dredging out St. John Chrysostom's issue after 1,700 years MUST includes studying the historical context before one could offer a defense, which I doubt a contemporary defense is warranted after a lot has happened since then which SJC couldn't possibly anticipate (such as the holocaust).  Without that context it is definitely not wise revisiting the issue.  As C.SE question goes, I think question #3 has to be separated out as a historical question, not a contemporary position.

@GratefulDisciple that is why I labeled "a defense would be nice", but I'll make it more clear.

You ask if historical Christian-Judeo relations in the early Church persist in this modern era". Well, of course they do. Even a blind man on a galloping horse could see that, without any answers needing to list modern era hostilities between the two groups. There may be a question of degree. There may be a question of whether one side is more hostile to the other side. There may be a question of shift in focus as reasons for hostilities. Yet, that is not what is asked for here. It is a simple Yes or No question, and my answer is a simple Yes.
Stirring up ancient hostilities is never a good idea, but seeking to understand why hostile thoughts, feelings and actions persist over centuries is. To reasonable people, there are understandable reasons for hostility against all groups involved in those realms of religion. But the trouble is, and always was, focusing on a religion and its adherents, rather than on the person of Jesus Christ (as in this question). Let's face it - No Jesus of Nazareth - no Christianity. A Jesus of Nazareth who died but was never resurrected by God - no Christianity.
The problem that needs to be honestly faced up to by all hate-filled religious groups is, "What's your problem with the founder of Christianity?" After all, he told his followers to love their enemies, and to pray for those persecuting them. He said that if someone smote them on the cheek, to offer their other cheek to the smiter. And so on. The fact that huge numbers of professed Christians over the centuries have done the opposite is no reason to hate what Jesus stood for and exemplified. This simply causes the focus to shift from what Christianity is about and to give vent to hatred. It takes away attention from the amazing things God did, in Christ, to dwell on the ghastly things imperfect, sinful people have done. Oh how the Great Deceiver must delight in that!
Jesus said, "I am the light of the world; he that followeth me shall not walk in the darkness, but shall have the light of life." John 8:12 A.V.
This question asks about " a step into darkness". Well, to get out of that centuries-old darkness, my answer is, let people start following Christ, or get back to truly following him, and see what an incredible difference that makes to their feelings of hostility.

The problem isn't that Christianity is anti-Jewish, it's that some organizations advertised as Christian are anti-Jewish (and anti-Christ). Most people will see only the anti-Jewish attitude presented by false Christianity. They lack the details you described above, so have no reason to think this is not what Christianity is about. True Christianity is a small flock, not a huge world-wide religion. "For many shall come in my name, … and shall deceive many", "But evil men and seducers shall wax worse and worse, deceiving, and being deceived.", "Satan, which deceiveth the whole world".

I like this answer. Ultimately I'm not attempting to stir up trouble, I'm more trying to understand a modern issue. I've made the point that many call themselves "christian" but are in no way act like them. Just like Ray points out. As far as I can tell Anne, the issue they have with Jesus is that it breaks one of the 3 "die before you do them" sins. (Murder, Sexual immorality, and Idolatry) so... that's the issue, Jesus claimed to be "Gd" as they would say.

@Wyrsa  Indeed - it is Jesus' own claims to be God that lies at the root of this massive issue. Only if modern efforts to meld different religions into an amorphous blob succeed, will (false) claims of overcoming entrenched hatreds be made. Then anyone persisting in saying Christ is God incarnate will be hung out to dry Big Time, what few are left, those having resisted this amalgamation process. Then things will get even darker for them, but nothing compared with the blackest darkness that awaits for... ah, well, who?

"The fact that huge numbers of professed Christians over the centuries have done the opposite is no reason to hate what Jesus stood for and exemplified." +1  We neither hate them nor shy from proclaiming the truth so that they might be saved.

Christian Antisemitism Pervasive in Modern Times
I am a nondenominational Christian who believes in Jewish roots of Christianity, that gentile Christians are merely grafted in the Israeli religion.
The historical Christian antisemitism does indeed persist today, though in a subtle cultural and passive form. For the historical Christian antisemitism, see Michael Brown's book: Our Hands are Stained with Blood. Though the Vatican has apologized to the Jews for their historical antisemitism in the last decades with a favourable shift in their theology and politics. It has only been a result of the global political shift, which is dominated by left wing passive-aggressive politics. Thus, where the old antisemitism was a punitive form of replacement theology, the new one of the 20th and 21st century is the economic and structural replacement theology which does not directly punishes and persecute the Jews, but merely allows the persecution by remaining indifferent to it through its support for certain politics which punishes the traditional culture and civilizations for being oppressors. Though, the greatest support for Israel comes from some Christian sects that developed in Biblical knowledge by departing from institutional religion to personal and direct learning of the Bible over the centuries. There are still various antisemitic factions within the traditional and non-traditional sects (Catholic or Protestants).
Pope Pius XII marked the beginning of positive perspective to the Jews. While he did not publicly advocate for the establishment of Israel, he privately supported Jewish communities during the Holocaust. He took steps to shelter some Jews and encouraged others to help them. The Vatican did not formally recognize Israel until 1993, long after Pius XII's death in 1958. His successor, Pope John Paul II, played a significant role in establishing diplomatic relations with Israel. Vatican Council II (1962-65) shifted towards Ecumenism (harmony and unity among Christian sects), promoted individual religious freedom, and also acknowledged opposed antisemitism. The document Nostra Aetate addressed the Church's relationship with Jews, stating that they should not be seen as rejected by God and renouncing the charge of deicide (see Matthew 27:25). It also emphasized respect for other religions, acknowledging the truth and holiness present in them. As a reaction to this reform of the Vatican II, certain traditionalists broke away from the Catholic Church. The positive acceptance of Jews is evidently one of the key reasons for their separation. SPLcenter writes Radical Traditional Catholicism:

Adherents of radical traditional Catholicism, or “integralism,” routinely pillory Jews as “the perpetual enemy of Christ,”... In their own words:
“Adolf Hitler was merely the end-product of what had been championed
by the Freemason Otto von Bismarck sixty years previously. Bismarck
started a Kulturkampf against the Holy Faith. Hitler’s own
quasi-religion, Nazism, was simply result of four hundred years of
revolution against the Divine Plan to effect man’s return to Him
through His Catholic Church, a revolution that was aided and abetted
by Talmudists at every turn.”
– Thomas Droleskey, in an article on the Christ or Chaos website, Feb.
19, 2023
“We have Jews all over the world. What, 14 million of them? Some
liberal, you know, reforms. Some conservative. Hasidic Jews. Some in
the middle. They have no recourse to the Catholic Church. As a matter
of fact, they come in, and they try and change church doctrine to suit
the Jews.”
– Robert Sungenis in an April 27, 2021, YouTube video titled “Is There
Salvation Outside the Catholic Church?”
“Here is my contribution for the inter-religious dialogue between
Catholics and Jews: ‘Catholics, don’t trust the Jew; he hates you and
is just playing games. The whole Vatican II dialogue with the Jews is
a pantomime to distract your attention and destroy Catholic militancy
against Judaism.’”
– Atila Sinke Guimarães, in an article on the Tradition in Action
website, Aug. 31, 2015

The popular right wing antisemites of mainstream media personalities have been suspected adherents of this traditionalist Catholic group. This branch of antisemites merely peddle the traditional conspiracy hoaxes of blood libel against Jews to draw cultural hatred through lies. In my opinion, the work of both the left wing reformed mainstream Catholicism and the right wing traditionalists, both serve as indirect tool to continue the agenda of wiping out Jews. Both sides indirectly facilitates the genocidal antisemitic entities whose mission is to destroy all Jews, especially in their homeland.
This is why top university presidents openly defended genocidal rallies against Israel in America, in the congress hearing. The majority of Christians in the Middle East openly support the anti-Israel stance, and favour antisemitic groups. While the Jews have experienced unspeakable persecution for two millennia in the form of genocides and torture, and now they are unable to freely reside in their own homeland. The antisemites living in the holy land often mock and provoke the orthodox Jews, such as by intentionally shoving their idol processions on the street at the same time when those Jews arrive there, and they end up being arrested merely for spitting in disdain. Cases of deliberate vilification of Israeli authorities over basic security protocols in the ancient Church crowd control, and many such habitual antisemitic lies, are very common.
I am not interested in addressing the rhetorical article of the Orthodox scholar who defends antisemitic Church fathers, though it can be easily refuted once we find the underlying presumptions. The excuses to justify vile genocidal antisemitism by painting the words as rhetorical and intellectual context is a dishonest deflection. Moreover, the ignorance of justifying some "rabid antisemite" Rose Rand, merely on the basis of her being Jewish is very dangerous, as this fallacy assumes that a Jew cannot possibly be an antisemite Jew hater; her academic acheivements have no bearing on her sinful ideology, we are not judging her intelligence or talent. Hitler, for example, was a brilliant painter, it is irrelevant. There are far left wing Jewish groups even in Israel, which are the most rabid and vile antisemites in supporting global genocidal regimes and groups against Israel. Just as there are far left white racists against whites. Their identity does not absolve their hatred. Sometime, people can be so blinded by hatred that they do not see they are working for their own annihilation.

The underlying presumption from that article is that things should be properly held in historical context and that to not do so is willful intellectual negligence. Interesting answer, pity though.

The words cannot be disassociated with the actual history of genocide and persecution throughout the times. It is like denying the history of persecution itself. The words of church leaders have been rightly interpreted, in the context of the history as they had been enacted upon by the troops. This phrase "who shall rid me of the turbulent priest?" is often used by Shmuley Boteach against vile antisemites who try to come across as clean and legal in their public statements of vilifying Jews, to rid of any responsibility, bec they manage to substitute "Jews" with some abstract obscure term

The words from... ~300AD?

Are you implying there was no physical persecution of Jews by the Church after Constantine's conversion, murders, massacres? If so, you should ask for references in Judaism SE or read that book by Dr Brown for detailed research.

No, why would I? It would be like denying the 2 centuries before it. Or using modern words in a 1 to 1 translation with ancient texts. It would intellectually malevolent and lead to more sin in the form of even more hate.

My perspective is from Eastern Orthodoxy.
I have only addressed my 3rd question, a defense for Chrysostom, but my 2nd question should be answered via the historical context argument made below.

I had to dig a bit and found a "deleted" article on the subject of anti-semitic christianity (It was deleted very recently it seems, possibly due to the war in israel or people getting offended? idk)

Was St. John Chrysostom Anti-Semitic? (link to waybackmachine) (Author is Anonymous, but is an Orthodox scholar)
Anti-Semitism is a complex issue in the Fathers, since the position of the Jews, over the centuries, has changed from that of a sometimes violently anti-Christian religious and social force to that of a victimized people. The same Jews who mistreated and victimized the early Christians, something often overlooked in contemporary historical sources, have in our times been the victims of mistreatment themselves. This observation must be seen, of course, through the prism of the Zionist policies pursued in the establishment of the Israeli State and the subsequent violence against the Palestinian people, many of them Orthodox; but certainly, as civilized people, we must recognize and loudly decry the atrocities visited on the Jews (and many other peoples, of course) during WW II. Ultimately, then, as I shall emphasize below, we should not glorify or vilify the Jewish people, but understand them in historical context: sometimes as persecutors themselves, sometimes as the persecuted. ...  to call anti-Semitism a single thing and to discuss it outside of historical context is to deal wrongly with the historical record.
As well, it must be remembered that the Fathers of the Church view Jews as the adherents of a religion, as a spiritual entity, not merely as a race. And even when they use the word race, they also mean it in a spiritual way, not simply as we use it today. (Thus "Judaizers" was an accusation made against non-Jews as well as Jews. And sinners are sometimes called a "race.") These distinctions are lost on contemporary dilettantes, who think that the curse on the Jewish race applies exclusively to people of a single blood line, rather than to any person who, like the hypocrites of the Jewish establishment of Christ's time, perpetuate anti-Christian sentiments. A "Jew" can, once more, be a Gentile who makes a mockery of Christianity within the Christian Church. It is obvious, then, that the term "Jew" is used in a number of very special ways in Patristic literature. (We True Christians, in fact, are called, by the Fathers, the "New Israel" and "Israelites," in the sense of remaining loyal to the whole Covenant of God's Providence which the Jewish religious leaders violated and defiled.)

This article is not entirely helping my perspective, but let's continue... yikes.

Calling any Church Father anti-Semitic on the basis of ostensibly denigrating references to Jews, therefore, is to fall to intellectual and historiographical simple-mindedness. Applying modern sensitivities and terms regarding race to ancient times, as though there were a direct parallel between modern and ancient circumstances, is inane.

Alright, that makes sense. Ancient times are not modern times, language is not a 1to1 thing...
It goes on with this author pointing out that this accusation towards Church Fathers is similar to claiming that any of them thought of females as "lesser" or many other things. (Which is of course not the case, the first Christian was female, women were apostles to the apostles, etc)
The author then continues and takes the example of St. John Chrysostomos, who is one of the most harsh church fathers towards the "jews" after all he calls them "pigs" their temple "a house of demons", he associates them with nonspiritual endeavors, with drunkeness,... but in the modern era he points out we would not use such language. The author uses a modern example of "Who would call the Japanese "J*ps" today? It was common in WW2", and how that was acceptable due to the war.
So the author then goes into historical context. And points out that the Jews were very hostile at the time. And the church fathers were deeply upset that the religious leaders were kill the Christ.

...these things must be put in the context of the hostility which Jews themselves had against Christians (as heretics and idolaters, added by me) and the fact that the Christian Fathers found abhorrent the rejection of the Messiah by the Jews. St. John's statements are expressions of theological and "ideological" (if I may use this somewhat inappropriate modern term) outrage, not of racism. It speaks for itself that he *(that is St. John Chrysostom, added by me)*also praised the Jewish Prophets, those Jews (including the Apostles) who accepted Christianity, and even preached, like all of the Church Fathers, against the wrong or violent treatment of Jews. These things, of course, are seldom mentioned by those who want to make a racist of him. One exception, by the way, is an April 27, 1998, editorial in "Christianity Today" (Vol. XL, No. 5, p. 12), which makes some of the same points that I do in defending Christians against a film presented at the National Holocaust Museum in Washington, DC, a documentary that holds Christianity responsible for Nazism (an outrage which even some Jews have decried). Finally, the Divine Chrysostomos was a great rhetorician. Much of his language reflects the rhetorical devices of his time, not the personal antipathy which a reader jaundiced by the "nicety" of modern discourse might attribute to him. This must be remembered at all times when reading him and other Church Fathers.

The author continues and bluntly insults those who use out of context quotes, quotes out of historical context, etc. to formulate their opinions. It is rather rude, but ultimately a valid point because blasphemy which is supported by ignorance is a very dangerous force if it gains social acceptance. (Demonizing a race for example...)
The author then admits, there is much naive, unthinking, un-Christian anti-semitism among even the Orthodox Church, who's wrong views are supported by truthful memories of the harsh treatment of the early church in the hands of the jewish religious leaders. I however have repeatedly pointed out, the actions of a few people should not stain an identity. This would be like making concentration camps for random japanese people during WW2 in the USA... oh, wait a second. What I'm saying is we should definitely not be doing actions like that.
The author continues and points out that the "modern enlightened" world is objectively just as horrible as the "ancient world" was. We still have genocide and all manner of bigotry.

I do not deny, by the way, that there is much naive, unthinking, and un-Christian anti-Semitism among some Orthodox Christians, whose wrong views are, nonetheless, supported by certain truthful memories, embedded as they are in the historical consciousness of our Church, of the harsh and undeniable mistreatment of Christians in the Early Church by the Jews: a consciousness which we do not hold in common with Western Christians, who are separated from the Apostolic Church and their original Christian roots and who therefore lack such memories. The naked anti-Semitism of some Orthodox people (which I do not endorse, and for which reason I have been ridiculed), however, pales, as I said above, before the putrid bigotry of those who, steeped in the hypocrisy of the modern world and its widespread historiographical disdain for the beauty of the age of the ancient Fathers, attribute to the Patristic witness the filthy racism and human denigration of human beings that belong as much, if not more, to our times and to the heterodox than to the ancient world and our Orthodox forefathers. And whereas modern man lays claim to supposed enlightenment, yet still practices racial genocide and is beset by the worst forms of bigotry, at least ancient man had his alleged social "primitiveness" to justify whatever injustices he may or may not have in fact embraced.
I would avoid people who like to dismiss the Patristic witness because of flaws in the character of the Fathers, whether real or imagined. I befriended at Princeton a brilliant philosopher (Rose Rand), then an old woman, who was one of Wittgenstein's few female students. She was a rabid anti-Semite. But this did not make her philosophy inadequate. It did not invalidate her brilliant insight into some very intricate theories about human thought and language. The same could be said of the Fathers. If perchance some were anti-Semitic (and again, to say this unreservedly and without a clear definition of terms is to nullify the meaning of intellectual history and to use language wrongly), does this mean that the Truth which they taught was tainted by their anti-Semitism? I think not. To say so is, again, simple-mindedness and ultimately constitutes an anti-intellectual stand. And anti-intellectualism, despite its moldy and revolting presence in some Orthodox circles, is inimical to the Patristic spirit.
The matter at hand is, once more, complex. It should not be discussed with people who lack an appreciation for that intelligent shade of gray that lies between the antipodes of white naivete and lack ignorance. As a case in point, Dr. Rand, my aformentioned, virulently anti-Semitic friend, was a Polish Jew!

I mean this author basically wrote the intellectual equivalent of a brick and threw it. But it is the first defense of "anti-jewish" teachings of the church fathers I've seen so far.
The argument seems valid for my 2nd question, it requires historical context.
My 1st question should be obvious, clearly modern christianity is not anti-semitic, even the rough words of the article I found are not "anti-jew", they are "anti-ignorance" and "anti-malevolent-intellect".

yawn, downvote with no advice on how to improve
